# How can I subtract from inventory using Stripe Elements

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I was using a pre-SCA Stripe integration in my webapp that used Checkout. The flow basically:

- Did `\Stripe\Order::create` against a selected SKU and quantity so that I ensured that inventory was still available (for products with 'finite' quantity)
- Then an `\Stripe\Order::retrieve` and `$order->pay` using the token passed back to me by Checkout in the client.

I've rebuilt my integration with an SCA-compliant flow, now with Stripe Elements, for a better UX.

However, I don't see how I can check against inventory when using Elements. There doesn't seem to be a way to use Elements with a similar Order, Retrieve, Pay flow.

Can anyone that's got a similar Elements based integration point me toward how to making sure I don't oversell products with limited quantity.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [Stripe official Order](https://stripe.com/docs/orders/create-and-process) is the flow you are looking for. I am not sure whether you have found it yet, but basically it's to create Order, Retrieve and Pay flow with Payment Element, also SCA-compliant.